# Loop through a directory, tar each subdirectory to a destination folder

Tags: bash, find, tar

I'm trying to loop in the SOURCE directory, tar each subfolder to DEST directory without success.
I've tested a few variations, but none is acceptable, so I'm looking for some help.
These are the closest ones.

Thanks

Structure:

```
/srv/source
    sub1
    sub2
    sub3
```

I would like to have a tar for each sub as this:

```
/srv/dest
    sub1.{DATE}.tar.gz
    sub2.{DATE}.tar.gz
    sub3.{DATE}.tar.gz
```

These where the tests I made:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date '+%Y.%m.%d')
SOURCE=/srv/source
DEST=/srv/dest

find ${SOURCE} -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' -execdir tar zcvf ${DEST}/{}-${DATE}.tar.gz -C ${DEST}/{} . \;
```

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date '+%Y.%m.%d')
SOURCE=/srv/source
DEST=/srv/dest

for DIR in "$(find ${SOURCE} -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | xargs -0)"
do
  tar zcvf ${DEST}/${DIR}-${DATE}.tar.gz -C ${SOURCE}/${DIR} .
done
```

**EDIT:**

This is working

```
for DIR in ${SOURCE}/*
do
  [ -d "${DIR}" ] && tar zcf ${DEST}/$(basename "${DIR}")-${DATE}.tar.gz -C ${SOURCE}/$(basename "${DIR}") .
done
```

Comment: Your second script looks fine (other that you really dont need to use `find` a simple `ls` would do).  So what is the problem with your second script?

Comment: Why aren't they acceptable? What's wrong? And ignore the comment above, never parse the output of ls.